# Sync MAC folder with FAT external drive for backup - Bash rsync command has different behaviour between local folders end external drive folders

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm running this command from a bash script

```
rsync -avzh $SourceFolder/ $DestinationFolder
```

If I run it with both SourceFolder and DestinationFolder as local folders (both on my MAC) it behaves correctly. Meaning that it copies new files and overwrites the newer versions to the DestinationFolder.

If I run the script using an external drive folder as a DestinationFolder, it copies and overwrites the whole content of the SourceFolder.

How can I avoid that, having the script to overwrite only newer versions of the files instead of the whole content of the SourceFolder everytime?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this was downvoted, probably because the answer is already somewhere out there. Anyway I thought it was a specific enough question.

After some hours here's how I fixed my script. The key was in the `--update` and `--modify-window=1` rsync command options.

Here's the working script (with the addition that I am excluding files from an external file).

```
#!/bin/sh

ScriptName=${0##*/}

# this script sync SourceFolder with DestinationFolder 
# to a FAT32 external drive, excluding files from ExcludeFile 

### --- EDIT FOLDERS HERE --- ###
SourceFolder='/Users/matteo'
DestinationFolder='/Volumes/HITACHI/MatteoMainFolderBackup'
ExcludeFile='/Users/matteo/.backupignore'

### --- DISPLAY SOME INFO --- ###
echo "Starting " $ScriptName
printf "WARNING! This script sync all files from SourceFolder to DestinationFolder \n"
echo "SourceFolder: " $SourceFolder
echo "DestinationFolder: " $DestinationFolder
echo "ExcludeFile: " $ExcludeFile
printf "### Start Syncing files ###\n"

### --- OPERATIONS --- ###
rsync   --archive \
        --delete \
        --delete-excluded \
        --exclude-from=$ExcludeFile \
        --modify-window=1 \
        --progress \
        --update \
        --verbose \
        $SourceFolder/ $DestinationFolder

### --- END --- ###
echo $ScriptName " ended"
```